# Pandas fill column with multiple lists

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to fill two pandas columns with multiple lists of different sizes.
So for example I have the first column with a list like "angioplasty, aortic, artery" and the second one like "251, 2882, 401, 4019, 412"

First I tried to append each list like this:

```
matches.code_matches.append(code_series)
```

which resulted in this TypeError:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'list'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid
```

So I tried converting the lists into a series and append them to the dataframe with this code:

```
code_series = pd.Series( (v[0] for v in code_matches))
matches.code_matches.append(code_series)
```

However after appending the series my Dataframe still ends up empty.

What is the best way to fill the columns of a Dataframe different sized lists? Note that i want to keep the lists and fill them into single fields instead of filling in each element separately (i want to assign the values to ids)

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
In [704]: l1 = ['angioplasty', 'aortic', 'artery']

In [705]: l2 = [251, 2882, 401, 4019, 412]

In [707]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': pd.Series(l1), 'b': pd.Series(l2)})

In [708]: df
Out[708]: 
             a     b
0  angioplasty   251
1       aortic  2882
2       artery   401
3          NaN  4019
4          NaN   412
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the `.at` method in the code below and it seems that worked.

```
x = pd.DataFrame()

x['A'] = 1,2,3,4,5,6
x['B'] = 1.0,2,3,4,5,6
x['C'] = 9,8,7,6,5,4

x['D']=0
x['D']=x['D'].astype('object')

for i in range(len(x)): x.at[i,'D'] = list(np.random.rand(3))
```

You can replace the `list(np.random.rand(3))` with your own data.